# Send powershell commands multiple users

Tags: penetration-test, metasploit

My apologies if this is not the correct forum for this topic but needed to know, currently, what C2 platforms allow send commands to multiple clients at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.